# Doctrine cannot redeclare class Annotation

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, annotations, doctrine

i've got my bootstrap

```
    <?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

// Log Filename
define ('LOG_FILENAME', 'clicktocall-'.date("Ymd").'log');

$loader = require "vendor/autoload.php";
// Doctrine parser
Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

// Create a simple "default" Doctrine ORM configuration for Annotations
$isDevMode = true;
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array("./src/acme"), $isDevMode);

// Database configuration parameters
$dbParams = array(
    'driver'    => 'pdo_mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'user'      => 'xxx',
    'password'  => 'yyy',
    'dbname'    => 'zzz',
);

// Obtaining the entity manager
$em = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

// Setting Logger Monolog
$Logger = new \Monolog\Logger('CTLogger');
$Logger->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('./log/'.LOG_FILENAME, \Monolog\Logger::INFO));
```

When i'm trying to execute

```
vendor\bin\doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force
```

I obtain this message

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Annotation in E:\www\acme\vendor\doctri
>   ne\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Annotation.php on line 22

I'm just using Doctrine bundle.
Any idea?
Thanks a lot

[Edit]
I've found that the problem is caused by
    Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

I use this row to parse the annotations for the symfony\validator bundle, without this the validation doesn't work...